# Discord.py find all messages from user and check content of each message

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to know if there's any way in discord.py to check for every message sent by a user and get the bot to look for every occurrence of a specific word or list of words and return the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually, using the `channel.history` method, pass a check function that will check if the message is sent by the user, here's an example

```py
def check(message):
    return message.author.id == some_author_id

messages = await channel.history(limit=100, check=check).flatten()
# Now you have 100 messages sent by a user
# You can now iterate through every message and check whatever you want
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history)

Comment: `TypeError: Messageable.history() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check'`

Comment: @Ruri This answer was outdated w/recent updates to the API. This question as been answered again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564304/get-the-last-message-a-user-sent-using-discord-py).