# Get all messages sent by a specific user in a channel/server - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out a way to get all messages sent by a **specific** user in a channel and/or the whole server (would probably take a while for that).

I have also looked into `User.history()` and `Member.history()`, but despite the documentation not mentioning it, it will only return a User's DM history.

Here is the Bot Command code snippet:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['rq'])
async def randomquote(ctx):

    def check(ctx):
        return ctx.author.id == memberID

    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=100, check=check).flatten()
    await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(messages).content}")
```

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327986/discord-py-find-all-messages-from-user-and-check-content-of-each-message?rq=1), however, the `check=check` throws: `an exception: TypeError: history() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check'` ,although it does look like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answer appears to be wrong, there is no such way to build checks into `history`. Also, if you want all the messages by that user, you would need to remove the limit. You could, however, try one of these:

```py
messages = []
async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
    if message.author.id == memberID:
        messages += [message]

# Or...

messages = [msg for msg in await ctx.channel.history(limit=None).flatten() if msg.author.id == memberID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can get all messages in a channel and check if message's author is user:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['rq'])
async def randomquote(ctx):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=100).flatten()
    messages = [m for m in messages if m.author.id == memberID]
    await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(messages).content}")
```

Comment: Or make `member : discord.Member` a required argument and replace `memberID` with `member` so you do not have to reload the bot all the time/edit the code.