# How can I get the last message that arrives in discord

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to get the last message from X GUILD and Y CHANNEL that arrives in discord only to read it and print it into Phyton console but it's so confusing, there are tokens for bots and also the official API and it's a bit difficult for me to get through all it alone with my current knowledge level.

So, here's the code I've right now.
It's difficult for me to understand sync and async functions too.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def get_message(CHANNEL_ID):
    msg = await client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).history(limit=1).flatten()
    msg = msg[0]
    print(msg)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(get_message("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))

main()
```

Please, can anyone help? I'll be much appreciated!!!
The thing I want to do is very simple but it's so difficult for me.

Comment: Would this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578181/2359945) which fetches message history of a channel help you?  It looks like you could adapt to your scenario, and is more general purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The Python Discord library is completely based around events. For example, when a message happens, you will receive an event about it that you can respond to. We use async functions because most actions with the Discord API has a delay and we want to continue doing other things while we are waiting for the API response.

This makes is hard to just get the last message. We can still do it by creating a background task that waits until the API is connected, gets the message and then quits.

Based on the example here:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py

```
import discord
import asyncio

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # create the background task and run it in the background
        self.loop.create_task(self.get_message(1111111111111))

    async def get_message(self, CHANNEL_ID):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        msg = await self.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).history(limit=1).flatten()
        msg = msg[0]
        print(msg)
        await self.close() # close client once we are done


client = MyClient()
client.run('your token here')
```